# Find the equation of the ellipse whose symmetry axes are given by $x+y-2=0$ and $y-x-1=0$. Also semi width $a=2$ and semi height $b=1$.

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> Find the equation of the ellipse whose symmetry axes are given by $x+y-2=0$ and $y-x-1=0$. Also semi width $a=2$ and semi height $b=1$.

As the center can be found at the intersection of the symmetry axes, I found that the center is at $C\big(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\big)$. As the center is symmetry center for ellipse, symmetrical points on the first and the second symmetry axes do also belong to the ellipse. Those points are $2$ and $1$ units far from the center. Hence, they are of the form $$A_1\big(\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{2},\frac{3}{2}+\sqrt{2}\big), \ \ A_2\big(\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{2},\frac{3}{2}-\sqrt{2}\big), \ \ B_1\big(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big), \ \ B_2\big(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big)$$
Now I have 5 points that lie on the ellipse of a general form: $$Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2+2Dx+2Ey+F=0$$ And by plugging them into the equation I may probably find the coefficients. However, this seems to be a lot of irrational computations :(

Could anyone suggest me a wiser way to solve this problem?

Comment: $(\frac{(x-\frac12)+(y-\frac32)}{\sqrt{2}})^2/2^2+(\frac{(y-\frac32)-(x-\frac12)}{\sqrt{2}})^2=1$

or 

$(\frac{(x-\frac12)+(y-\frac32)}{\sqrt{2}})^2+(\frac{(y-\frac32)-(x-\frac12)}{\sqrt{2}})^2/2^2=1$

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland How did you find this?

Comment: I wrote the lines in a form that conserves the distances, then it's just choosing which semi-axis has length what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the canonical equation below

$$\frac{x^2}2+ \frac{y^2}1=1$$

First, rotate 45 degrees, i.e. $x\to \frac1{\sqrt2}(x+y)$, $y\to \frac1{\sqrt2}(-x+y)$

$$\frac{(x+y)^2}4+ \frac{(x-y)^2}2=1$$

Then, shift the center $x\to x-\frac12$ and $y\to y-\frac32$ to obtain

$$\frac{(x+y-2)^2}4+ \frac{(x-y+1)^2}2=1$$

Comment: Thank you! How do I know in which direction to rotate?

Comment: @VIVID - There are two possibilities. I just assumed that the major axis is at 45-degrees with the x-axis, while the other is at 135-degrees.

Comment: So we rotate to the angle equal to the angle between major axis and the $x$-axis, right?

Comment: @VIVID that is correct

Comment: Then if you take this angle equal to 45-degrees, your rotation matrix would be of the form $$\begin{bmatrix} \cos 45^{\circ} & -\sin 45^{\circ} \\ \sin 45^{\circ} & \cos 45^{\circ} \end{bmatrix}$$ So that $x \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x-y)$ and $y \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x+y)$. But you got something little bit different...

Comment: @VIVID the matrix rotates the axes. The answer rotates the ellipse, which is the inverse of the matrix

Comment: Doesn't rotating the axes also rotate the ellipse?

Comment: @VIVID yes, but in opposite direction. I.e rotating axes -45 is the same as rotating curve 45

Comment: Inverse of that rotation matrix is $$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}$$ so $x \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x+y)$ (same as yours) but $y \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-x+y)$ (different).

I'm sorry for my questions, but I really want to learn it well :)

Comment: @VIVID - no problem. You’re right. It is $y\to \frac1{\sqrt2} (-x+y)$. The result remains the same though due to square. Will correct

Comment: Thanks! It seems to me that finding its inverse is equivalent just to rotating to $-45^{\circ}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108343/discussion-between-quanto-and-vivid).

Comment: Agree, here we go

Answer (score 1):

I think this  would be an easier way:First I want to talk about simpler ellipse $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$ we know that major axis of this ellipse is $y=0$ and minor axis of the ellipse is $x=0$.Now i am trying to see the equation in terms of these two axes.If we observe $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ clearly we can get that  it's more like $$\frac{(\text{distance of general point}(x,y) \text{ from minor axis})^2}{(\text{lenght of semi major axis})^2}+\frac{(\text{distance of general point}(x,y) \text{ from major axis})^2}{(\text{lenght of semi minor axis})^2}=1$$ and i think applying this techinque to this question would be of a great help.Hope that helps!

Comment: I think this idea might be a bit clearer if you pointed out that the $x$-coordinate of a point is its (signed) distance from the $y$-axis and vice-versa. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3677133/265466) is in much the same vein.

Answer (score 0):

HINTS:

The slopes of given lines are, using slope-intercept form are  $ =\pm1$, a rotation by $ + 45^{\circ}.$

By distance formula for end points of major/minor axes you found is calculated as

$$ d_{A_1A_2}^2= ( 2 \sqrt2)^2+  (2 \sqrt2)^2 = 16 \tag1 $$

so the major axis length is ( square root and half)  $ \;a=2$

Similarly  $  b=1 $

*Quite beneficial* to adopt parametric form

$$ (  x,y)= ( a \cos t ,b \sin t) \tag 2 ) $$

First rotation by $ \pi/4$ standard rotation relation:

$$ ( x_1,y_1) = [(x-y)/\sqrt2/,(x+y)/\sqrt2 ]\tag3  $$

Next displacement of ellipse center to $ C (\dfrac12, \dfrac32) =(h,k) $ say

$$x_2=( x_1+h); \; y_2=(y_1+k) \tag4$$

If you want to convert to $(x,y) $ form by trig elimination of $t$, that is up to you.